# Checkbox ON/OFF switch in Safari and IE/Edge

Tags: html, css

In Chrome, firefox, opera, brave ia ok, in Safari - transition no good.
In Edge, Internet Esplorer - apprearance not work, looks like the checkbox
How to repear safari's transition and apprearance in Edge/IE browsers?

```css
.mytoggle {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-out;
  transition: .25s ease-out;
}

.mytoggle:before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  z-index: 2;
  content: "ON OFF";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #7f8c9a;
  font-size: 14.99px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: -32px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-out;
  transition: .25s ease-out;
}

.mytoggle:checked {
  background-color: #2A3542;
}

input.mytoggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.mytoggle:checked:before {
  background-color: #41cac0;
  color: #41cac0;
  left: 54px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="mytoggle" style="" />
```

Comment: ATM there's 3 answers from three different users each posting code that looks different and all 3 get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling a checkbox directly is a pain, you could use the checkbox + label hack, in which you link a label to a checkbox, and apply the styles to the label instead of the checkbox itself:

```css
.mytoggle {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999px;
}

.mytoggle + label {
  font-family: arial;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-out;
  transition: .25s ease-out;
}

.mytoggle + label:before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  z-index: 2;
  content: "ON OFF";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #7f8c9a;
  font-size: 14.99px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: -32px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-out;
  transition: .25s ease-out;
}

.mytoggle:checked + label {
  background-color: #2A3542;
}

input.mytoggle:focus + label {
  outline: 0;
}

.mytoggle:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #41cac0;
  color: #41cac0;
  left: 54px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="mytoggle" id="mycheckbox" />
<label for="mycheckbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input { opacity:0}
input+label {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-out;
  transition: .25s ease-out;
}

input+label:before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  z-index: 2;
  content: "ON OFF";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #7f8c9a;
  font-size: 14.99px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: -32px;
  word-spacing: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-out;
  transition: .25s ease-out;
}

input:checked+label{
  background-color: #2A3542;
}

input.mytoggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

input:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #41cac0;
  color: #41cac0;
  left: 54px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="abc" checked="checked"  style="" />
<label for="abc" class="mytoggle"></label>
```

I just added a label for input checkbox, tested in internet explorer 11. I don't have have safari browser to test it, So you can test and let know, if this answer meets your requirement.

Comment: Works in Safari 13

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".ra-box").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] { opacity: 0; }
.ra-box { 
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 6px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
    background: #2a3542;
    width: 70px;
    height: 18px;
 position: relative;
}
.ra-box:before {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: #41cac0;
 color: #41cac0;
 content: 'ON';
 text-indent: -40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 right: 5px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.ra-box:after {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: #7f8c9a; 
 color: #fff; 
 content: 'OFF';
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-indent: 30px;
 left: 85px;
}

/* Check Box Check Change background color */
.ra-box.checked:before { right: 85px; }
.ra-box.checked:after { left: 5px;}
.ra-box.checked { background: #bdc3c7; }

.ra-box,.checked,.ra-box.checked,.ra-box:before,.ra-box:after,.ra-box.checked:before,.ra-box.checked:after {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ra-box">
 <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="ra-box">
 <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: I just added a div tag with a class "ra-box" and applied js and fired toggleClass event.

Comment: How to put that displays "ON" or "OFF" automatically if it has attribute checked="checked" or no? '<input type="checkbox" checked>'. In Safari the transition is still not smooth.